# Google Translate API and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, google-translate, google-translation-api

Anybody can show an example of using google translate api for silverlight with source code?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client which has provides .Net bindings for lots of the Google Apis including translate. If you down load the [samples](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/20111123-1.1.4344-beta/Generated/ZipFiles/google-api-dotnet-client-1.1.4344-beta.samples.zip) you will find samples for the Translate API and WPF samples, though not a WPF Translate example.

You can also just browse the source code and look at the [Translate Sample Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Translate.TranslateText/Program.cs?repo=samples)